# Left JOIN 2 tables with more than one result

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables

fist one customer

```
id, name
1, Adam
2, Sam
3, Erik
```

second one orders

```
id, father_id , order
1, 1, 1000
2, 1, 2000
4, 2, 4000
5, 3, 600
6, 3 , 433
```

the php output should be

```
Adam : orders : 1 - 1000 , 2 - 2000
Sam : orders : 4 - 4000 
Erik : orders : 5 - 300 ,  6 - 433
```

How could I do the output in this case  using left join method 
Im lost

Comment: output usually doens't combine results like that however, group_concat()with your join should do it... though I don't know why a LEFT join is needed... Inner seems like it would work..  Do you want all customers regardless if they have an order or all orders regardless if the cusotmer record isn't there anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  c.id,
  c.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(o.id,' - ',o.order))
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN orders o
ON c.id = o.father_id
GROUP BY c.id
```